# Android how to load different images in a webview after short time intervals

Tags: java, android

Im implementing a small app which having a webview.i want to load different images (banners) on top of it.here is my current working..

my xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true" >

 <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

 <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

my java code..(still not implement multiple image load in small intervals part )

```
 public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);



    // Getting reference to WebView of the fragment_one layout
   mWebView = (WebView) root.findViewById(R.id.webview);
   mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
   mWebView.loadUrl("http://thailandshoponline.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Thailand-      Shop-Online-Banner-2.gif");


    return root;
     }

    }
```

i think i have to use timer to delay the refreshing task.but i doesn't know the proper way of doing it..please help

Comment: anyone know how to do this, please let me know